# Integrating difficult equation which has a simple answer for a constant but steps not provided

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate the right hand side of:

$$2\pi \cot\beta = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{q}{R}\right)^2\cos\phi d\phi$$

I have:

$$q = \frac{b\cos\phi\sin^2\beta - \sqrt{\sin^2\beta(R^2\cos^2\phi - b^2\sin^2\phi) + R^2\sin^2\phi}}{\sin^2\beta\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi}$$

$\beta$ and R are known and are constant.  b is constant but unknown.  I'm ultimately trying to use these two equations to solve for b.  The solution is:

$$b = R\cot\beta$$

but no steps are provided on how this solution for b was obtained. I can't figure out how this solution was arrived at given the complexity of the expression for q.

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat anticlimactic answer of how the authors found the solution is almost certainly "by plugging it into Mathematica or similar software".

However, if you wanted to calculate the integral by hand, then here is how I would approach it:

1. Apply some symmetries to reduce the integral to something of the form $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.
2. Convert all of the $\cos^2 \phi$ terms into $1 - \sin^2 \phi$ and simplify.
3. Replace all the complicated terms with simpler values (e.g. if $1 + \sin^2 \beta$ shows up a lot in the integral, set it equal to $A$).
4. Use the substitution $u = \sin \phi$, because that makes everything collapse into rational and radical terms that are much easier to integrate.

Comment: I'll give your suggestions a try and post back.  Just so you know, the authors published their paper in 1964, so it's doubtful that they used computer software.  I'm  not familiar with applying symmetries, so I'll need to do some studying on this.

Comment: Once I simplify as you suggest, I still need to square the simplified expression for q and multiply by $\cos\phi$, correct? The resulting expression still seems to be pretty ugly.

Comment: I would treat $q$ as a function of $\sin^2 \phi$ and $\cos^2 \phi$ for as long as possible. And remember that when you do the substitution in step 4 you'll have $du = \cos \phi d\phi$ so you don't need to move that last $\cos \phi$ term anywhere since it will disappear. As for applying symmetries, I mean things like showing that the integral of the function between 0 and $\pi$ is the same as the integral between $\pi$ and $2 \pi$, so you can calculate the smaller integral and double it. And there should be a similar result to shrink the interval down by another half.